# Display as many views that will fit using ViewThatFits, prioritizing views added first

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a number of items that I want to display but not all of them will fit in the available vertical space. I want to show as many as possible. `ViewThatFit` almost does the trick, but it prioritizes displaying the last items added. I want to prioritize the first items so any of the later items that won't fit are not visible.

In this example code, I want One to always be visible and the last items should be cut out if they don't fit (Seven then Six etc). Instead what's happening is Seven is always visible and One then Two etc is cut out.

Is there a way to achieve this with `ViewThatFits` or is there another approach I could take?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                RowView(title: $0)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
        .background(.fill)
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    let title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits {
            // If this VStack won't fit in the available space, it'll use a 0 height view instead
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(title)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                
                Divider()
            }
            
            Color.clear
                .frame(height: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot showing Four, Five, Six, and Seven]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use layoutPriority to solve your issue. You can modify your code like that:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                RowView(title: $0)
                    .layoutPriority(
                        Double(items.count - (items.firstIndex(of: $0) ?? 0))
                    )
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
}
```

Comment: Totally works, thank you very much! 